# JAVAFX - Tableview with modifiable custum TimePicker cell close too quickly

Tags: javafx, tableview, timepicker

I have a Tableview with modifiable custum TimePicker cell.
I wrote a function that listens the changes in that cell but when I click on a specific hour, the clock doesn't stay open and close at the first click and i have to click again to select the minutes for exemple.
How can i let the clock open and make the editCommitEvent() when the clock close?

Thank you for your help :)

Here is the code of my custum cell.
PS: I use jfoenix TimePicker

```
public class TimePickerTableCell<Patient> extends TableCell<Patient, LocalTime> {

    private JFXTimePicker timePicker;
    private boolean listening = true;

    // listener for changes in the timePicker
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    private final ChangeListener<LocalTime> listener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (listening) {
            listening = false;

            TableColumn<Patient, LocalTime> column = getTableColumn();
            EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Patient, LocalTime>> handler = column.getOnEditCommit();

            if (handler != null) {
                // use TableColumn.onEditCommit if there is a handler

                handler.handle(new TableColumn.CellEditEvent<>(
                        (TableView<Patient>) getTableView(),
                        new TablePosition<Patient, LocalTime>(getTableView(), getIndex(), column),
                        TableColumn.<Patient, LocalTime>editCommitEvent(),
                        newValue
                        ));             

            } else {
                // otherwise check if ObservableValue from cellValueFactory is
                // also writable and use in that case
                ObservableValue<LocalTime> observableValue = column.getCellObservableValue((Patient) getTableRow().getItem());
                if (observableValue instanceof WritableValue) {
                    ((WritableValue) observableValue).setValue(newValue);
                }
            }
            listening = true;
        }
    };

    public TimePickerTableCell () {
        this.timePicker = new JFXTimePicker();
        this.timePicker.valueProperty().addListener(listener);

        this.timePicker.setOnMouseEntered((event)->{timePicker.requestFocus();timePicker.show();System.err.println("OUVERTURE TIMEPICKER");});
        this.timePicker.setOnMouseExited((event)->{if(event.getY()<23)timePicker.hide();});
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(LocalTime item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            listening = false;
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            listening = false;
            setGraphic(this.timePicker);
            this.timePicker.setValue(item);
            this.timePicker.getStyleClass().add("time-picker");
            listening = true;
        }
    }

    public static <E> Callback<TableColumn<E, LocalTime>, TableCell<E, LocalTime>> forTableColumn() {
        return column -> new TimePickerTableCell<>();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the reason the `JFXTimePicker` hides when you go to click the clock is (most likely) because of your `onMouseExited` handler. When you move your mouse over the popup it "exits" the `JFXTimePicker` and thus hides the clock.

You're also implementing an editable `TableCell` the wrong way. You should be overriding the [`startEdit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#startEdit()) and [`cancelEdit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#cancelEdit()) methods of the [`Cell`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html) class (which `TableCell` inherits from). You can look at the source code of classes like [`TextFieldTableCell`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTableCell.html) for how it's done. I also worked up an example for doing this with `JFXTimePicker`:

```
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTimePicker;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.util.converter.LocalTimeStringConverter;

import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class TimePickerTableCell<S> extends TableCell<S, LocalTime> {

    // Static methods for creating TableColumn.cellFactory Callbacks

    public static <S> Callback<TableColumn<S, LocalTime>, TableCell<S, LocalTime>> forTableColumn() {
        return v -> new TimePickerTableCell<>();
    }

    public static <S> Callback<TableColumn<S, LocalTime>, TableCell<S, LocalTime>> forTableColumn(DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
        return v -> new TimePickerTableCell<>(formatter);
    }

    // Formatter property

    private final ObjectProperty<DateTimeFormatter> formatter = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "formatter");
    public final void setFormatter(DateTimeFormatter formatter) { this.formatter.set(formatter); }
    public final DateTimeFormatter getFormatter() { return formatter.get(); }
    public final ObjectProperty<DateTimeFormatter> formatterProperty() { return formatter; }

    // JFXTimePicker field

    private JFXTimePicker timePicker;

    // Constructors

    public TimePickerTableCell() {
        this(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME);
    }

    public TimePickerTableCell(DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
        getStyleClass().add("time-picker-table-cell");
        setFormatter(formatter);
    }

    // Display logic

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(LocalTime item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        setGraphic(null);

        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText(formatItem(item));
        }
    }

    private String formatItem(LocalTime item) {
        if (item == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return getFormatter() == null ? item.toString() : getFormatter().format(item);
    }

    // Edit logic

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        if (!isEditable() ||
                !getTableColumn().isEditable() ||
                !getTableView().isEditable()) {
            return;
        }
        super.startEdit();
        if (isEditing()) {
            if (timePicker == null) {
                createTimePicker();
            }
            timePicker.setValue(getItem());
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(timePicker);

            // Wrapped this in a Platform#runLater call because otherwise
            // I couldn't get this to work properly. Despite this, there are
            // times where this still seems buggy.
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                timePicker.requestFocus();
                timePicker.getEditor().selectAll();
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setText(formatItem(getItem()));
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    private void createTimePicker() {
        timePicker = new JFXTimePicker();

        timePicker.setConverter(new LocalTimeStringConverter(getFormatter(), null));
        formatter.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                timePicker.setConverter(new LocalTimeStringConverter(newValue, null)));

        timePicker.getEditor().setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                commitEdit(timePicker.getValue());
                event.consume();
            } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                cancelEdit();
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        timePicker.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (!newValue) {
                cancelEdit();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here, if the `ESCAPE` key is released or if the `JFXTimePicker` loses focus then the edit is cancelled. It appears that interacting with the clock does not cause the `JFXTimePicker` to lose focus (at least when I tried it).

If you want to commit the edit you have to press the `ENTER` key. This works (again, at least when I tried it) even if the clock is currently showing.

This doesn't commit the edit automatically when the clock closes but you should be able to add that behavior if desired. Since `JFXTimePicker` extends from `ComboBoxBase` it has properties such as `onHiding` and `onHidden`.

*Note: If, after typing the time manually, you attempt to commit and the `DateTimeFormatter` is unable to parse the `String` it simply reverts to the old value. There is no indication of any error other than the fact the value hasn't changed. This seems to be behavior caused by the `JFXTimePicker`, however.*

---

You also don't need to try and handle committing the value yourself, either. The `TableColumn` already attempts to set the new value on the underlying property by default. This is mentioned in the Javadoc of [`TableView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) (under the "Editing" header, **emphasis** mine):

> When you call `Cell.commitEdit(Object)` an event is fired to the
>   `TableView`, which you can observe by adding an `EventHandler` via
>   `TableColumn.setOnEditCommit(javafx.event.EventHandler)`. Similarly, you
>   can also observe edit events for edit start and edit cancel.
>
> **By default the `TableColumn` edit commit handler is non-null, with a
>   default handler that attempts to overwrite the property value for the
>   item in the currently-being-edited row**. It is able to do this as the
>   `Cell.commitEdit(Object)` method is passed in the new value, and this is
>   passed along to the edit commit handler via the `CellEditEvent` that is
>   fired. It is simply a matter of calling
>   `TableColumn.CellEditEvent.getNewValue()` to retrieve this value.

If you do end up using your own `EventHandler` in `setOnEditCommit` then you need to implement the behavior yourself:

> It is very important to note that if you call
>   `TableColumn.setOnEditCommit(javafx.event.EventHandler)` with your own
>   `EventHandler`, then you will be removing the default handler. Unless
>   you then handle the writeback to the property (or the relevant data
>   source), nothing will happen. You can work around this by using the
>   `TableColumnBase.addEventHandler(javafx.event.EventType,
>   javafx.event.EventHandler)` method to add a
>   `TableColumn.editCommitEvent()` `EventType` with your desired `EventHandler`
>   as the second argument. Using this method, you will not replace the
>   default implementation, but you will be notified when an edit commit
>   has occurred.